RDS events subscription to SNS for daily snapshot
I am trying to achieve the exports of automated or manual snapshots that are done daily for my RDS Cluster which has 2 instances for 2 separate regions.
I have a Lambda code(with according permissions) to export the snapshot of cluster
and when I test is manually, it works to export.
Now, I want to make it automatically run by a SNS Topic. In the SNS Topic should arrive the RDS Event from RDS Events Subscription that is linked to my SNS Topic.
The problem is that I can see the daily event created once the backup/snapshot is created but it is not trigger my Lambda code. What I am doing wrong?
I set the permission for SNS to trigger my lambda, it is showing as "Confirmed" with my lambda, I've enabled the Delivery Status Logging with role/SNSSuccessFeedback.
My Topic has the access policy set:
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:Publish",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:Subscribe"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxxxx:RDS-Snap-Notifi-us-west-2",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "xxxxx"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "rds.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxxx:RDS-Snap-Notifi-us-west-2"
    }
  ]
}

Now, the settings for Event Subscription should be:
Source Type: Cluster snapshots ?
Specific Event: backup ?
When I select Cluster Snapshots, I cannot select the Cluster I need and/or Cluster snapshots to include:
All cluster snapshots (not sure if will help me?)
Select specific cluster snapshots ( I can select specific snapshots, but I need to have an option the specific snapshots of specific cluster, not all of them( I can see all snapshots for both clusters).
What I am doing wrong?
LE: I see there is a problem with the SNS message... because if I test my lambda code with lambda test action having the json below, lambda success and job export is starting:
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "Sns": {
                "Message": "{\"SourceArn\": \"arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:xxxx:cluster-snapshot:abc-date\"}"
            }
        }
    ]
}

but if I publish same json as message from SNS Topic to My Lambda, it arrives and I can see in CloudWatch logs the ARN Invalid Format. There seems to be a issue with how SNS Topic send the message format.
Any thoughts?
Thank you!
